# C++: Cannot compare double from an array of structures to another double in if function

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, comparison

int i = 0, gr = 1;
    double otlichen6 = 5.5;

```
for (gr = 1; gr <= 4; gr++)
{
    int nqmaotl = 1;
    cout << "Otlichnici ot " << gr << " grupa: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int nqmaotl = 1;
        if (students[i].srusp >= otlichen6 && students[i].grupa = gr)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << students[i].ime << "   " << students[i].faknom << "   " << students[i].spec << "   " << students[i].grupa << "   " << students[i].srusp << endl;
            nqmaotl = 0;
        }
```

The problem is with the first comparison in the if function. I cannot compare students[i].srusp (where students is an array of structures, and each of those structures contain the element srusp which is double type) with double otlichen6 which equals 5.5 , even when I just compare students[i].srusp with 5.5 it still doesn't work.
The errors I get are:
1. E0137    expression must be a modifiable lvalue
2. C2106    '=': left operand must be l-value
I switched their places and it still says "left operand must be l-value), which I have no idea what it means.

Comment: `students[i].grupa == gr` missed a `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&& students[i].grupa = gr

> Blockquote

in above code,
= is an assignment operator
you need == for a comparison operator

Comment: This is just a worse-edited version of the comment left by Matthieu Brucher 15 minutes earlier.

Comment: Oh thanks, I work with like 5 different versions of a bigger program, each with its own errors and I forgot what I've fixed in this one and what isn't fixed in this one and forgot about the single =.